# Стоит ли обновлять Wordpress до версии 4.0?

Tags: html, wordpress, update, php, mysql

Вышел новый **wordpress 4.0**. И в админке 3.9 он уже хочет обновится.

Вопросы:

1. Каких нюансов следует ожидать от обновления?
2. Придется ли модифицировать тему оформления?
3. Есть ли вообще смысл в обновлении или лучше оставить так, как есть?

---

*Спасибо за понимание моих переживаний.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Например [тут](https://wpmag.ru/2014/wordpress-4-0/), а лучше [первоисточник](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.0) (и вообще всячески рекомендую читать кодекс всем, кто работает с WP).
2. Скорее всего, нет. Если только вы используете очень старую тему, которая очень давно не обновлялась и использует какие-то функции ядра WP, которые в этом релизе выкинули. Но WP чертовски консервативен, так-что такое случается редко.
3. Есть.

Обновлять WP надо. WP очень популярная CMS, поэтому в ней ищут, находят и исправляют баги, в том числе серьёзные, в общем-то достаточно часто (кажется, в каждом обновлении есть что-то про безопасность). Если WP не обновлять, то останешься со своими проверенными временем уязвимостями, которые уже точно найдены и широко используются добрыми людьми (и, что хуже, добрыми роботами) для не очень добрых целей. То же самое касается его плагинов и тем.

Проблемы при обновлении ядра WP (или тем, или плагинов) могут возникнуть, если вы сами вносили изменения в ядро WP, темы или плагины. Ваши изменения просто будут затёрты обновлением. Поэтому нельзя редактировать WP/плагины/темы наиболее очевидным образом (просто взять и отредактировать), нужно использовать более хитрые методы. Для изменения поведения ядра WP нужно использовать плагины, для изменения тем существует механизм дочерних тем (создаётся дочерняя тема, производная от основной, и изменения вносятся в неё).

В общем, если WP готовить правильно, то обновления - совершенно безболезненный процесс. Если WP готовить неправильно, то нужно учиться готовить его правильно (или не использовать его), а не сидеть без обновлений.

Кстати, WP обновляется очень часто (и это правильно), так что привыкайте.

P.S. А резервную копию перед обновлением всё-таки сделайте, лишняя резервная копия лишней не бывает.

Comment: P.P.S. Приду домой, обновлю свой зоопарк.